# ResetDirectory causes a fail on stored file names

Tags: files-and-directories, counting

Consider some directory `dir` with sub dirs and files. Our aim is to count the no of files in dir (not in sub-dirs, just the dir.)

```
dir="C:/folder";
SetDirectory[dir];
names = FileNames[];
Length@Select[names, FileType@# == File&]
(*2*)
```

There were in fact 2 files and 6 sub-dirs.

```
FileType /@ names // Tally
(*{{Directory, 6}, {File, 2}}*)
```

Now consider the following code

```
dir = "C:/folder";
SetDirectory[dir];
names = FileNames[];
ResetDirectory[];
Length@Select[names, FileType@# == File &]
(*0*)
```

Here even though we saved the file names in `names`, the count is `0`. Why is this? Why is a directory reset affecting stored file names?

Comment: "Why is a directory reset affecting stored file names?" - it is not.  The variable `names` is set before you called `ResetDirectory`.  It isn't clear from your code what the contents of `"D:/rough"` are, or what you expect the final `Length` to be.

Comment: @JasonB. sry about that.....the dir in both cases is same

Comment: Something about the code you've posted still doesn't make sense.  Try replacing `names = FileNames[];` with `names = Echo @ FileNames[];` and see if it doesn't clarify for you what is happening.

Comment: @JasonB. here's the echo of the file names `{1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat6,dat7,rough2.wls,rough.wls}`. The last two are the files...its still registering 0 length

Comment: I understand now - the list returned by `FileNames` contains *relative file names*, and are only findable *from the same directory*.  If you need them to be full file paths, try `names = ExpandFileName /@ FileNames[];` and see if that works better.

Comment: @JasonB. "findable from the same directory" got it... so `FileType` actually reaccesses the files to ascertain their type? thats why relative paths don't work......thnx I'll accept if you post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Herein lies the issue:

```
In[6]:= SetDirectory[$UserDocumentsDirectory];
files = FileNames[];
SetDirectory[$UserBaseDirectory];
CountsBy[files, FileExistsQ]

Out[9]= <|False -> 54, True -> 1|>
```

The filenames returned by [`FileNames`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNames.html) are given *relative* to the current path, and so when the path changes they aren't valid filenames.

To get around this limitation, use [`ExpandFileName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandFileName.html) to make sure you always have an absolute file path.  In the above, use

```
files = ExpandFileName /@ FileNames[];
```

In the snippet above the only file that returns `True` from `FileExistsQ` is easily guessed by any OSX user:

````
In[11]:= Select[files, FileExistsQ]

Out[11]= {".DS_Store"}
```
````